# calling Web service from iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services

There is a file `iPhone.asmx`, which is written in vb.net and is hosted on a server. I need to access that web service without using SOAP. How can I do that?

Comment: Surely the with/without SOAP decision comes down to the web service exposed by `iPhone.asmx`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on that [website](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43209/0/page/1), it is possible to call a WS without SOAP in the iphone. You only have to pass the parameters of your WS in the query string. 
So your code will look like :

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL initWithString:@"http://host.com/WS?param1=val1&param2=val2"];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest initWithURL:url];
 NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES ];
```

Comment: thanx for ur reply ,so no need to send the parameters in the xml format?

Comment: Yeah, you only have to pass the parameters in the query string if you are using a GET method. All the explanations are on the website. Good luck

Comment: hii ,,am passing the parameters as u mentioned but am getting error( expected ':' before '@'token)am using this code NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xxxxxxx.net/IPhone.asmx?strFrom=@"support@xxxxxxxxxx.net"&strRecp=@"rg.ravi89@gmail.com"&strSub=@"Problem"&strBody=@"Test""];

Comment: show me your code. The prob maybe is with your Objective-c code